# Grail partial view for ajax request

Tags: grails, partial-views

```
<g:if test="${!request?.xhr}">
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="home">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row-fluid">
</g:if>
AJAX
<g:if test="${!request?.xhr}">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</g:if>
```

I get error: `Grails tag [sitemesh:captureBody] was not closed.`

In `Config.groovy` I set `grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = false` but this doesn't help.

What way to use partial view with if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to handle this in grails is to wrap a template containing the main content.  For example:

```
//_body.gsp
AJAX

//view.gsp
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="home">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <g:render template="body">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then your controller can render the whole view on a regular request, or just the body on AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `request.xhr` in the controller, and determine to render a template or a string based on the results of that if statement.